# Copying one 16TB folder onto several consecutive 8TB drives on a standalone Freebsd

Tags: freebsd, ntfs, truenas

I have a very old server that stores 16Tb of data. It is running FreeNAS (freebsd). Network cards are physically damaged and the server is on its last breath.

I have 2 8TB NTFS external hard drives. I'm trying to copy all those files into hdd1, and whatever won't fit on it into hdd2. Hard drives are mounted into /mnt/hdd1 and /mnt/hdd2

I have just enough space and incredible complicated file structure I can't just copy couple folders onto one and everything else on another drive. I would need some script to do that. Any suggestions?

Again, it's just freebsd with no UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Install rsync
2. Run the following script

```
    cd /path/to/data
    rsync --recursive --relative . /mnt/hd1 || (
        find . | sort > /tmp/source.lst
        cd /mnt/hd1
        find . | sort > /tmp/hd1.lst
        diff -ab /tmp/source.lst /tmp/hd1.lst | tail -n +4 | grep -v ^- > /tmp/copied.lst
        cd /path/to/data
        rsync --recursive --relative --exclude-from=/tmp/copied.lst . /mnt/hd2
    )
```

If installing `rsync` is not an option, you can do some tricks with lists of files and copying one by one using `while` and `cp`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. It does looks exactly what I'm trying to find. rsync is installed on the system so it should be fine. Another problem it can't recognize my harddrives, but I think I'll be able to handle that.

Comment: @NewRK, if the answer does look exactly what you're trying to find, please mark the question as answered and upvote it. Thanks.